# Why can't I import datepicker with jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, typescript, datepicker, aurelia

I'm trying to reference this site for using/importing jquery-ui's datepicker element: 
http://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/02/using-jquery-ui-widgets-in-aurelia/

My first obstacle is trying to import it into my class. If I just do a regular

```
import 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';
```

it imports it fine, but I can't reference the "datepicker" object. If I import it like the website tells me too:

```
import 'jquery';
import { datepicker } from 'jquery-ui';
```

I get an error on the 2nd `import` statement about how it can't find the module. Like I said at first, if I just `import 'jquery-ui'`, then below in my code, it doesn't recognize the `$(this).datepicker();`

If I just run the app, I get a normal input box but no datepicker This is the error I'm getting from bluebird.min.js:

Unhandled rejection TypeError: jquery_1.default is not a function

What's the **right** way to import this library and use it?

**Full Custom Element Code**

```
import { customElement, bindable, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';

@customElement('date-picker')
@inject(Element)
export class DatePicker {
    @bindable id = '';
    @bindable name = '';
    @bindable options = {};
constructor(Element) {
    this.element = Element;

    if (!this.id && this.name) {
        this.id = this.name;
    }

    if (!this.name && this.id) {
        this.name = this.id;
    }
}

attached() {
    $(`#${this.id}`).datepicker(this.options)
        .on('change', e => {
            let changeEvent = new CustomEvent('input', {
                detail: {
                    value: e.val
                },
                bubbles: true
            });

            this.element.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
        });
}

detached() {
    $(`#${this.id}`).datepicker('destroy').off('change');

}
}
```

**HTML Part**

```
<template>
    <input type="text" id.bind="id" name.bind="name">
</template>
```

Comment: which module loader are you using? systemjs or webpack?

Comment: @FabioLuz systemJS

Comment: Regarding $(this).datepicker() problem... Check if you have two jQuery versions in your config.js file. I'm constantly fighting with this. Usually, there's a jQuery version from github - "jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.2.4", installed as a dependency of Bootstrap. You might get another version from npm by installing other libraries, like jquery UI. Check the dependencies of jquery-ui lib in config.js.

Comment: @MiroslavPopovic i have a few instances in the config file.

"jquery": "npm:jquery@3.1.0" 
"jquery-ui": "github:components/jqueryui@1.12.0"  
"github:components/jqueryui@1.12.0": {
     "jquery": "npm:jquery@3.1.0"
}

Comment: is there any errors in console?

Comment: @FabioLuz No there isn't. It's just not converting the input to a datepicker. Keeping it as a textfield

Comment: you are probably missing the css file

Comment: put this in your html file, just for testing `https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-for rc.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css`

Comment: @FabioLuz Alright, I'm rebuilding it now and going to see if that will work. Did you get it to work on your environment?

Comment: I'm working right now, I don't have an environment. I can try this later when I get home

Comment: @FabioLuz Alright. Still not working for me.

Comment: @FabioLuz I just tried it in Chrome and I'm getting an error:
Unhandled rejection TypeError: jquery_1.default is not a function

Comment: @FabioLuz and that error is coming from the bluebird.min.js file

Comment: you should import jquery without curls, like this `import $ from 'jquery';`

Comment: @FabioLuz I've tried both. I've actually changed it to it without curlys. Changing it above now. I am getting a syntax error from VSCode on the '$' FYI

Comment: are you using typescript?

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. After hours of installing/uninstalling types/packages, etc. It works if I import it into my typescript file as follows:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';
```

I can't believe it's that easy after all the time I've spent...